# How to prove two definitions of antisymmetric are equivalent

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

The first definition of antisymmetric of a relation is $(a,b) \in R$ and $(b,a) \in R \implies a=b$. There is another saying if $a \neq b$ and $(a,b)\in R$, then $(b,a) \not\in R$. I could intuitively understand this or even by truth table, but I want to show how to transform one into another. I had gone with contrapositive and logical equivalence, neither work out. Here is what I got so far:
$a\neq b \implies (a,b)\not\in R $ or $(b,a)\not\in R$ I cannot go further with this one.

Could someone show me how to do it, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p$ be $(a,b)\in R$, $q$ be $(b,a)\in R$, and $r$ be $a=b$.

$(p\wedge q)\to r$ is equivalent to $p\to( q\to r)$ is equivalent to $p\to( \neg r\to \neg q)$ is equivalent to $(p\wedge \neg r)\to \neg q$.

Comment: Nice !! Thank you so much! Exactly what I am looking for

Comment: @LawrenceGuo The best way to say thanks here is upvoting and accepting the answer

Comment: @Matthew Daly I don't see why does $ (p\wedge q) \to r $ is equivalent to $p\to( q\to r)$